# Alternative for grub for autoloading last choice

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, grub-efi

Could  you suggest alternative for grub for autoloading an OS of last choice without timeout? 
I have tried to configure GRUB, but unsuccessfully - boot loader or not be showed, or  set up timeout to 10 sec by himself

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried. How did you configure grub? What configuration have you tried? What didn't work as expected?

Comment: At that moment the grub have this configuration:
`GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
#GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

If i set the value to 0 for timeout then it set automatically to 10 sec by himself. Same i probably set value to true for GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER, but after i can't open show menu at all